# Sprite animation and remove

Tags: iphone, animation, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I want to animate a fruit when it is touched by the squirrel hero in my game.After animation the fruit must be removed from the scene.I have been trying it for 2 weeks,not getting it right though.my spritesheet have 6 frames for sprite animation.

currently i am doing below code when hero intersects fruit :

```
            NSMutableArray *burst = [NSMutableArray array];

            for(int i = 1; i <= 6; ++i) {
              [burst addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Fruit01000%d.png", i]]];
            }

            CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:burst delay:0.02f];
            CCActionInterval *animAction = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO];


            [expl stopAllActions];
            expl.visible = TRUE;
            expl.position = ccp(coinColl.position.x,coinColl.position.y);

            cleanupAction = [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(explOver:) data:expl];
            seqF = [CCSequence actions:animAction, cleanupAction, nil];


            [expl runAction:seqF];     


            [platformLayer removeChild:coinColl cleanup:YES];
            [self sumScore]; 
            [coinLabel setString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",appDelegate.coinScore+appDelegate.levelScore]];
```

explOver() function :

```
-(void) explOver:(CCSprite*)explosion{
    explosion.visible = FALSE;
}
```

Its working partially,some fruits doesnt show animation and also app crashes when jumping to next scene,giving an error "pointer being freed was not allocated"

Comment: Look at [this awesome code](http://www.raywenderlich.com/7261/monkey-jump) and see the logic of animation of banana when monkey touches it. :)

Comment: i am not using any physics editor.

Comment: what problem do you actually have? you cannot detect collision of the squirrel with fruit or you don't know how to remove sprite after animation is finished?

Comment: collision works well,animation and removal is the problem.

Comment: @SpencerWong it is the fruit position retrieved from tilemap.

Comment: What is the different between 'expl' and 'explosion'? Your code is not complete..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely remove the sprite from your game layer, you can add category to CCNode class as this one.

```
@interface CCNode(CategoryName)
- (void) removeFromParentAndCleanupYES;
@end

@implementation CCNode(CategoryName)
- (void) removeFromParentAndCleanupYES
{
    [self removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
}
@end
```

then you can add this method call after running any action using sequence:

```
id animate = // any action, CCAnimate in your case
id callback = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:_fruitSprite selector:@selector(removeFromParentAndCleanupYES)];
id sequence = [CCSequence actionOne: animate two: callback];
[_fruitSprite runAction: sequence];
```

this is just a suggestion, but it should work fine. It has sense if you need to remove your nodes with actions in several parts of your code.

---

Another variant is to use CCCallFuncN action that will pass your sprite as parameter to the given selector.

```
id animate = // any action, CCAnimate in your case
id callback = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(onAnimationDidFinished:)];
id sequence = [CCSequence actionOne: animate two: callback];
[_fruitSprite runAction: sequence];


- (void) onAnimationDidFinished:(CCNode*)node
{
    [node removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
}
```

Comment: it is not the problem with removing,even without removing,the animation is not working properly.please help me with the animation part.

Comment: make sure that you add frames from atlas to your spriteFrame cache before call [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Fruit01000%d.png", i]]

Comment: also, as I can see, you use single node to run all the explosion animation. it is wrong as you call stopAllActions. so, previously started animation will stop and will be run in the next place, if you will try to run it during previous animation.

Comment: please give a solution for that.

Comment: app is crashing when moving to levelUp scene,giving error "pointer being freed was not allocated"